# How to rewrite urls to remove .php in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Looking to make rewrite my urls so pages don't end in /.php.

For example, I want to make '/about.php' look like '/about' or '/about/'

Can anyone share the module to do this? If you have an nginx.conf or virtual.conf file example that shows this type of rewrite I would be grateful.

Obviously, I am a noob but trying to learn by example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) directive to check for a file with `.php` appended. For example:

```
try_files $uri.php $uri;
```

This will first look for `/about.php` and then process `/about` if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
 location /about/ {
  proxy_pass http://backend/about.php;
 }
```

or

```
# this will catch ALL files and rewrite ALL requests
 (like /blabla/file to /blabla/file.php)
# it is not tested , but I guess you will understand this :)

location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /$1.php break;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

or may be simplest way

```
location / {
    proxy_path http://backend$uri.php #append .php to all files
}
```

end remember that rewrite module is slow.. try to avoid it